# How to remove the tabs from the output while using grep command in bash?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, git-bash

Desired Output:

```
[3] print(Hi, How are you?)
[5] print(I'm good, how are you?)
```

But Output I'm getting:

```
[3]     print(Hi, How are you?)
[5]     print(I'm good, how are you?)
```

Command Im using:

```
grep -n -P "\t" $1 | awk --field-separator=":" '{print "["$1"]"$2}'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. special thanks for showing your efforts in form of code in your question keep it up could you please post sample of input also in your question that will give us more fair idea of your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You never need grep when you're using awk and using `:` as the field separator then printing `$2` and would truncate lines like `print(I'm good: I got paid)` to `print(I'm good` so don't do that.

You didn't provide sample input so it's a guess at what you want to do based on reading the code you provided that **doesn't** do what you want to do so YMMV but this may be what you want:

```
awk 'sub(/\t/,""){print "["NR"]", $0}' "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -n -P "\t" $1 | awk --field-separator=":" '{$2=$2; print "["$1"]"$2}'
```

Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102008/how-do-i-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-each-line-of-some-output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace every tab (`\t`) with space ( ) then considering that you applied `linux` tag, you might use [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) command like so

```
grep -n -P "\t" $1 | awk --field-separator=":" '{print "["$1"]"$2}' | tr '\t' ' '
```